# Check if a field in a certain row and column is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a *database* with a *table* consisting of columns `player1`, `player2`, `player3`... `player12`

I need to check if the column `player1` is *empty* in a certain row.

Here's what I have in **join.php**:

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';
$playername = $_GET['name'];
$tour_name = $_GET['tourname'];

if (isset($playername)&&
    isset($tour_name)) {
$query = "SELECT `tour_name` FROM `tournies` WHERE `tour_name` = '$tour_name'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);

echo mysql_error();
//mysql_query("UPDATE `tournies` SET player1='".$playername."' WHERE tour_name='".$tour_name."'");
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    header('Location: s.php');
    } else {
    echo 'not a win.';
    echo mysql_error();
    }
    } else {
echo 'Invalid username or tournament ID, please return to <a href="index.php">Home</a> and try again. Sorry.';
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is to find if a row is empty, all you need to do is to use an statement like <> '' to load only rows with values or = '' to load empty rows;
ex.
SELECT `tour_name` FROM `tournies` WHERE `tour_name` = '';

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use ***MySQLi*** instead of its predecessor, ***MySQL***. Here's the code that might help you:

**connect.inc.php**:

```
<?php

$connection=mysqli_connect("YourHost","YourUsername","YourPassword","yourDatabase");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

**join.php**:

```
<?php

include('connect.inc.php');

if(empty($_GET['name']) || empty($_GET['tourname']){ /* IF THERE'S NOTHING TO GET */
header("LOCATION:OtherPage.php"); /* USER WILL BE REDIRECTED TO OTHER PAGE */
}

else { /* ELSE IF NOT EMPTY */

$playername = $_GET['name'];
$tour_name = $_GET['tourname'];

$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `tour_name` FROM `tournies` WHERE `tour_name` = '$tour_name'");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

if(empty($row['player1'])){ /* IF EMPTY PLAYER1 COLUMN */
echo "Player 1 is empty";
} /* END OF IF EMPTY PLAYER1 */

else { /* IF NOT EMPTY */

echo "Player 1 is ".$row['player1'];

} /* END OF ELSE */

} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your while loop

```
    if($row['player1']==''){
     //your logic
    }
```